# cy.task does not perform update

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, sybase

I'm trying to get Cypress to perform an update on the database before running the test. I did it as follows but it doesn't work

**/cypress/plugins/index.js**

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    sybaseQuery() {

      var Sybase = require('sybase'),
        db = new Sybase('host', '4400', 'dbname', 'user', 'pass');

      db.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);

        db.query('', function (err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err);

          console.log(data);

          db.disconnect();

        });
      });
      return null
    }
  })
}
```

**test**

```
it('Dado que esteja preenchido a data de ultima consulta e numero de prazo de entrega', () => {

cy.task('sybaseQuery',"update dbo.CARTAO_USU_CARTAO_COMPLEMENTO set nr_prazo_entrega_cartao = '25' where nr_cartao =  '6035740409054753'")
```

Comment: Were you getting any errors? some stack trace would help.

Comment: I think you need to return `null` in the `db.connect` method or at least return something...

Comment: No errors appear, it just doesn't run the update

Answer (score 0):

See previous answer, you should use

```
sybaseQuery(queryString) {
```

not

```
sybaseQuery() {
```

and

```
db.query('', function (err, data) {
```

will do nothing.

It should be

```
db.query(querystring, function (err, data) {
```

Comment: I put it that way and it didn't work either

Comment: Even so, it's a step in the right direction. Clearly you can't expect an empty query string to do anything useful.